# A simpler way to combine html imports

Tags: javascript, php, polymer, html-imports

Is there a simpler way to combine all needed html imports on the fly using php. I'm working on a project an its contents are dynamically generated and cant always use vulcanize. Most of the time, my page might fail to load fully (on 1st load), or fail to include all imports. [Take a look at this page](https://www.platinumindustriespl.com/cms/)

On slow internet, you have to reload a few times for the browser to catch on and load all files (by caching some files on the previous reloads).

Currently i can get up to 115 (in over 2.8min) requests while loading the site.

I might put a permanent cache expire on the files, but isn't there a way i can reduce the requests by putting all known imports in 1 file on the fly using php so that only one a few requests are made on first load?

Subsequent requests need not be a bother as I'm importing them on demand from the user.

Comment: vulcanize should works well. 
can you tell why you cant use vulcanize??
You can use vulcanize to create file that have all the custom elements that you maybe will use,And import it.

Comment: @Alon - The paths are generated by a templating system, furthermore, some imports are added to the header during load time by php.

Comment: So why you cant create one file that loads alll the imports?
and use vulcanize

Comment: put all the import url into one file? then import it?

Comment: no.
Put all the imports into one file, make vulcanize on this file and then import only this file.